# Explaining method (x << n) | (x >>> (32 - n))

Tags: java, operators, byte

Looks like a simple method, but I can't understand how `|` works here:

```
/**
 * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left.
 */
private static int rotateLeft(int x, int n) {

    return (x << n) | (x >>> (32 - n));
}
```

First part `(x << n)`, where `<<` is binary left shift operator. The left operands `x` value is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right operand `n`.

The (x >>> (32 - n)) part, where `>>>` is shift right zero fill operator. The left operands `x` value is moved right by the number of bits specified by the right operand `(32 - n)` and shifted values are filled up with zeros.

But what is the purpose of `|`?

EDIT:
OK, I found that it is simple operator: "binary OR operator copies a bit if it exists in either operand". So the sequence is: `(x << n)`, then `(x >>> (32 - n))`, then `(left part result) | (right part result)`?

Comment: To combine the two parts?

Comment: [Java operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: jus a small example: x = 1001...0000 ..., n = 2: so `(x << n)` is `0100...0000` `(x >>> (32 - n));` shifts n top bits to the end, i.e. `0000...0010` bit wise or is `0100...0010`

Comment: btw `(x >>> (32 - n))` == `(x >>> -n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **bitwise rotate** operation shifts bits to the left, but also "rescues" bits shifted off the high end of the value and shifts them onto the low end. The `|` operation in that function combines the "lost" bits from the high end of the word — shifted down to the low end — with the remaining bits shifted up.

The shift upwards leaves 0 bits in the low end, so it's assured that the only 1 bits will be those that were set in the high end of the word before the rotation.

Answer (score 4):

`|` is the bitwise OR operation.

It often resembles the plus operator, since its' truth table is:

```
A  B   A|B
-----------
0  0   0
1  0   1
0  1   1
1  1   1
```

For example: 8 | 2 = 10 since 8 is 1000 and 2 is 0010 and so:

```
1000 = 8
0010 = 2
----
1010 = 10
```